# Recursive URL routing in Restlet

Tags: url, routes, restlet

I'm using Spring to set up a Restlet application, and I've got a point where I need URLs to be recursive. i.e.,

```
/something/filter/x/y/filter/a/b/foo
```

The pattern is, approximately:

```
/something(/filter/{p}/{q})*/foo
```

So there can be an unlimited number of filter fragments in the URL.

In the Spring XML it looks like this:

```
<bean id="router" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringRouter">
    <constructor-arg ref="parentRouter" />
    <property name="attachments">
        <map>
            <entry key="/filter/{filterAttribute}/{filterValue}" value-ref="filterExtractor" />
            <entry key="">
                <bean class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder">
                    <lookup-method name="create" bean="dataResource" />
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="extractor" class="ca.uhnresearch.pughlab.tracker.extractor.FilterExtractor">
    <property name="next" ref="router"/>
</bean>
```

So this starts, but I get a stack overflow in `org.restlet.util.WrapperList.iterator` when the app starts, so it looks like the recursive router/extractor initialization is breaking the Restlet initialization processes.

Two questions, therefore:

1. Does Restlet allow recursive routing? (The docs don't seem to touch on this)
2. What is the best way to implement recursive URL routes?

Answer (score 0):

Such approach isn't supported in Restlet. The only way I see to implement a thing like would be sub routers with with matching mode `startsWith`.

I don't know exactly what your use case is but wouldn't it better to leverage HTTP headers to put filter attributes / values in requests. I'm not sure that such approach is really RESTful ;-) but I'm interested in having more details...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: That's a shame, because it's a reasonable use case (IMHO) and the HTTP header technique is a bit of a cheat. One option would be a hacky router+extractor+looper that would chomp off as many filter fragments as it can before forwarding at the end (essentially a *-type regexy matcher equivalent), but I'm not good enough with the reference usage to know how to chomp. Another is to dump everything into a query string, but then it's decontextualized from the resource path. I don't really see how the startsWith gets me anywhere since there really might be zero matches.